# marionette example not working

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have all the HTML , JS code here on codepen : http://cdpn.io/nbuGB

I started learning marionette JS. Somehow this simple example is not working.

It throws error : 
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("contact:entities",function(){
    return API.getContactEntities; 
});
```

You need to write `API.getContactEntities()` otherwise you're returning a function reference instead of your contacts collection. This causes the undefined error.

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jALtq